# How to assess statistical significance when predictor has proportional-odds assumption relaxed?

Tags: statistical-significance, ordinal-data, ordered-logit

I am interested in understanding the relationship between SurveyGroup(levels=1,2) and food availability (ordinal variable: None < Inconstant < Constant). Because my response variable is ordinal, I have run a model using the clm() function from the ordinal package.

I've run the following model with confounding variables are predictors:

```
mod<- clm(food_availability~ SurveyGroup + Age + education + gender + PropLifeFeeding + 
observation + centrality_mean + temp_seasonal, 
data = subset(econmix2, econmix2$season=="spring"), Hess = TRUE)
```

But then when I use nominal_test() and scale_test(), SurveyGroup does not meet the assumptions. So, I specify it in the nominal argument, but then I don't have a coefficient estimated and it is instead in the thresholds section of the summary output.

```
mod<- clm(food_availability~ gender + PropLifeFeeding + 
observation + centrality_mean + temp_seasonal, 
nominal = ~ SurveyGroup + Age + education,
data = subset(econmix2, econmix2$season=="spring"), Hess = TRUE)

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
genderMale      0.015329   0.149843   0.102 0.918520    
PropLifeFeeding 0.188023   0.311829   0.603 0.546530    
observation     0.036880   0.010640   3.466 0.000528 ***
centrality_mean 0.209999   0.052579   3.994  6.5e-05 ***
temp_seasonal   0.000742   0.007174   0.103 0.917617    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Threshold coefficients:
                                  Estimate Std. Error z value
None|Inconstant.(Intercept)      -3.321715   0.680552  -4.881
Inconstant|Constant.(Intercept)   0.627151   0.482889   1.299
None|Inconstant.SurveyGroup2      1.074639   0.340853   3.153
Inconstant|Constant.SurveyGroup2  0.096961   0.169354   0.573
```

How do I assess the relationships between SurveyGroup and food availability then?